# How to add $_POST values in a multi-dimensional array (PHP)?

Tags: php, arrays, post

I know there may be sources for this out there but I'v tried everything and I'm still not getting the proper solution. That why I'm asking for you help out here.

I have a $_POST array and I want to put values in a an array. Here is the final out I want:

```
$response = [
             ['category' => 2, 'value' => "june"],
             ['category' => 5, 'value' => "may"],
             ['category' => 8, 'value' => "april"]
            ]
```

Here is the catch,the $_POST contains a value of an integer with a space in between and then a string eg '2 june', '5 may' etc

When I get this value, I split it using explode then I try to add the individual values into the response array. This is only adding just one result.

What I tried:

```
$response = [];

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

    $split = explode(" ", $value);
    $result = ['category' => $split[0], 'value' => $split[1]];

    $response[] = $result;

}
```

for some reason, the results are not as suggested above. Any ideas and suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post here how `echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST, true).'</pre>';` looks like

Comment: Also, what are the results you are getting?

Comment: i only get on result... @sand

Comment: **i only get on result... @sand** - I don't understand what you are trying to say. Just put this line of code on top of your script and put `exit;` after that, then post here what you see in browser. If you see nothing then seems your data is missing

Comment: Kindly, check my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Tajinere  Time to tidy up & resolve this question.  Unfortunately there was a misconception regarding the cause of your issue.  Because your array building method was not incorrect, this question becomes how to $_POST form data.  This changes your question to _very low or no value_ to future readers -- and should be considered for deletion.  Alternatively, if you pose the question: _How do I make my process better?_, then we can answer that and there may be some value for future SO readers.  I have provided two options to improve your process so that you can resolve this question.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, problem is in the $_POST. This is global array with submitted key-values data. You should NOT use

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
```

for parsing your data without any checks. This data is submitted by user, and not always they will have format you're waiting for.

For example, if you have a variable "dates" in your HTML form, you should be ready that `$_POST['dates']` will be an array of all of your '5 june', '7 july', etc. Don't forget to check and validate all user data you received. It's important by security reason too.

Your code (foreach body, without condition) is ok, I've checked it. Try to set `print_r()` before `explode()` you will see that your're working with an array, not with a string.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, this code was just a quick check, security measures are in place.. The reason is that the form has a lot of input field and i dont want to check for all of them one after the other. So i'm using formdata to post the data to said php script

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't have an issue with processing the data into the correct resulting array.  The onus falls on $_POST not holding the expected data.
All answers to this question are powerless to fix your $_POST data because no html form was supplied with your question.  The only potential value that can be offered is to refine your array building process.

Here are two methods that improve your process by reducing the number of declared variables:

Demonstration uses `$a=array('2 june','5 may','8 april');` to represent your $_POST array.

1. One-liner in a foreach loop:

   ```
   foreach($a as $v){
       $r[]=array_combine(["category","value"],explode(" ",$v));
   }
   ```
2. One-liner with no loop:

   ```
   $r=array_map(function($v){return array_combine(["category","value"],explode(" ",$v));},$a);
   ```

Using either process the resulting `$r` will be:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'category' => '2',
    'value' => 'june',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'category' => '5',
    'value' => 'may',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'category' => '8',
    'value' => 'april',
  ),
)
```

References for used functions:
[explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) , [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) , [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Comment: why you set $key variable, if you don't use it?

Comment: Why would this work where the OP's code doesn't? It's basically the same but written differently.

Comment: Sorry, I had to rush off to dinner and didn't double-check before posting it, I removed the `$key` variable.  My answer shows there is nothing wrong when the input array is as expected.  Victor is correct, the flaw is in the input array.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
    $response = [];
    // just for example use this one
    $data = "2 june, 5 may, 7 july";
    $temp = explode(",", $data);

    // and you can use this one for your case
    /*$data = $_POST['var_name']; // var_name is your variable name from $_POST
    $temp = explode(",", $data);*/

    foreach ($temp as $key => $value) {
        $split = explode(" ", trim($value));

        foreach ($split as $val) {
            $result = ['category' => $split[0], 'value' => $split[1]];
        }
        $respon[] = $result;
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    echo print_r($respon);
    echo "</pre";
```

the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [category] => 2
            [value] => june
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [category] => 5
            [value] => may
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [category] => 7
            [value] => july
        )

)
```

Comment: This answer assumes the incoming $_POST data is a csv string, but based on the OP's processing method, there is no reason to believe this is true.

Answer (score -1):

```
    $response = array();

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

    $split = '';
    $split = explode(" ", $value);
    $result = array('category' => $split[0], 'value' => $split[1]);

    $response[] = $result;

    }
```

Comment: setting key/value pairs in an array from post data. Thanks.

Comment: This answer uses more code than in the OP to achieve the same result.